# Is it possible to POST datatable as AJAX data to a server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using PHP and CodeIgniter. I add some dummy data to datatable below, and I want to save this data in a database. Is it possible to POST this datatable to a server as AJAX data?

If yes, how can I fetch it? What is the best way ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var t = $('#example').DataTable();
  var counter = 1;

  //// addrow
  $('#addRow').on('click', function() {
    t.row.add([
      counter + '.1',
      counter + '.2',
      counter + '.3',
      counter + '.4',
      counter + '.5'
    ]).draw(false);

    counter++;
  });
});
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url: base_url + 'personel/createPersonel',
  type: 'post',
  data: data // ??
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
  ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: `data: {datax : JSON.stringify(t.rows().data())},`  worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate the array into a variable that can be both sent to server and added to table

```
$('#addRow').on('click', function() {
  var rowArray = [
    counter + '.1',
    counter + '.2',
    counter + '.3',
    counter + '.4',
    counter + '.5'
  ];

  var postData = {row: rowArray};

  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'personel/createPersonel',
    type: 'post',
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      t.row.add(rowArray).draw(false);
      counter++;
    }
  });
})
```

Then receive the array as `$_POST['row']` in php